# three smallest numbers in an array, no Math.min method. Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to figure out how to find three smallest numbers. I've got 2 first, but I'm not sure how to find the third one. I can not use any methods which change the original array. Thank you.

```
let max_1 = 0;
    let max_2 = 0;
    let max_3 = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<compare.length; i++){
        let nr = +compare[i];
        if(nr > max_1){
            max_2 = max_1;
            max_1 = nr;
        }else if(nr < max_1 && nr > max_2){
            ?
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just for clarification: Can there be duplicate numbers and how should they be handled? If input is `3, 2, 1, 2, 4`, do you want the output to be `1, 2, 2` or `1, 2, 3`?

Comment: 1, 2, 3, no repetition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use reduce like below - it will return an array holding the 3 smallest numbers.

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,-1,-2, -2];
const threeSmallest = [...new Set(array)].reduce((a, b) => {
    if (a.length < 3) return a.concat(b);
    a.sort((x,y) => y - x);
    let index = a.findIndex(e => e > b);
    if (index > -1) {
        a.splice(index, 1);
        return a.concat(b);
    }
    return a;
},[]);

console.log(threeSmallest);
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept the answer to show that to other users too @Nat

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,4,5,3,3,2];
let arr = [...new Set(arr1)];
var i, first, second, third;

third = first = second = 2147483647;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length ; i ++)
{
    if (arr[i] < first)
    {
        third = second;
        second = first;
        first = arr[i];
    }
    else if (arr[i] < second)
    {
        third = second;
        second = arr[i];
    }

    else if (arr[i] < third)
        third = arr[i];
}
console.log(first+ " "+ second+" "+ third);
```

Comment: This does not eliminate duplicates. (See comments below OP)